# TFTP-Server with different instances

Tags: udp, debian, tftp

I'm trying to create an tftp server for multiple sites. The server have just one ip address (10.10.1.69), but have to handle more than one tftp "instance".

At the moment I've installed atftpd with two services in rlinetd an two seperated ports (6901 / 6902).

My phones are looking at port 69 (unchangeble). Those from site A (10.10.40.0/24) and those from site B (10.10.41.0/24).

How can I split this udp traffic reffering to the source-ip-range to one or the other port?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found ... via iptables.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --src 10.10.40.0/24 -i eth0 -p udp --dport 69 -j REDIRECT --to-port 6901
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --src 10.10.41.0/24 -i eth0 -p udp --dport 69 -j REDIRECT --to-port 6902
```

Thanks for listening ;)